# Can I use a chimney exhaust fan as a whole house fan?

Tags: exhaust-fan, ventilation, chimney

I would like to install a whole-house fan in my house but want to avoid putting an unsightly fan in my living room (the only place it could reasonably be installed).  I have a traditional brick chimney fireplace that I haven't used in 15 years, and I'm wondering whether I can just install a chimney exhaust fan instead of a whole-house fan?

Comment: Pulling air up the chimney will automatically get the coolest air in the room (near the floor where the fireplace is) instead of the hottest air (at the ceiling) where a normal whole house fan pulls air from.

Comment: Talk to an architect.  I'm sure there's an alternative placement possible for a 'normal' whole house fan.

Comment: Meanwhile,  how about a plan view of your house, and some info as to the existence of an attic or a crawl space above the ceiling, etc?

Answer (score 1):

You can add an exhaust fan to your fireplace but you won't get the CFM that you would with a regular whole house fan. I started out with trying an exhaust fan in my fireplace and could only get about 200 CFM. You would probably get less with a brick chimney. That fan  was only beneficial to the room where the fireplace was, the living room. I eventually added a whole house fan that's good for 3400 CFM. I installed it in a hallway so it has "access" to other rooms if their windows are open. It can cool down the house in a matter of minutes during the winter months in Florida. It vents into the attic. I had to add  many soffit vents so the attic could then vent to the outside. The fans normally come with a PCV or metal vent that automatically opens when the fan turns on. It isn't unsightly.